# How to output two characters as one single char?

Tags: c++

In my assignment, our function receives a string of words and returns a string with the words hyphenated, as defined by the following rules:

> 1. If a vowel-consonant-consonant-vowel pattern is found, hyphenate between the two consonants. Letters ‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’, ‘u’, and ‘y’ are vowels; all other characters are consonants.
> 2. If a vowel-consonant-vowel pattern is found, hyphenate before the consonant unless the second vowel is an ‘e’ and occurs at the end of the word.
> 3. The following character sequences are never divided by hyphens: “qu”, “tr”, “br”, “str”, “st”, “sl”, “bl”, “cr”, “ph”, “ch”. For the purposes of rules 1 and 2, each of these are single consonants.

For rule #3, I want to know how the character sequences can be read as a single consonant.

My code for the special cases is:

```cpp
bool isSpecialCharSequence(const char* input, int index)
{
    if (input[index + 1] == 'r' || input[index + 1] == 'R')
    {
        if (input[index] == 't' || input[index] == 'b' || input[index] == 'c' || input[index] == 'T' || input[index] == 'B' || input[index] == 'C')
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (input[index] == 's' || input[index] == 'S')
    {
        if (input[index + 1] == 't' || input[index] == 'l' || input[index] == 'T' || input[index] == 'L')
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    if (input[index] == 'q' || input[index] == 'Q')
    {
        if (input[index + 1] == 'u' || input[index + 1] == 'U')
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    if (input[index + 1] == 'h' || input[index + 1] == 'H')
    {
        if (input[index] == 'c' || input[index] == 'p' || input[index] == 'C' || input[index] == 'P')
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Right now, it works for everything except reading those characters as one single consonant instead of 2.

Comment: You can make a constant of `“qu”`, but it isn't a character constant. To handle this rule you'll need smarter logic. Has your course covered [State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)s yet? If so, this is probably where the assignment is headed. If not, the trick that the instructor expects you to use was likely covered in a recent class or reading.

Comment: And yes, C++ is often gross, but you don't have to rub it in our faces.

Comment: *For rule #3, I want to know how the character sequences can be read as a single consonant.* -- Rethink your design.  I think you painted yourself into a corner with trying to immediately implement 1 and 2, without thinking about 3.  When you have assignments like this, consider *all* the possible cases -- don't jump in and code up the easy ones first.

Comment: Don't restrict your thoughts to single chars only. Try to think about the string as sequence of tokens where each token may represent a substring of 1, 2 or 3 characters that are classified as consonant, vowel or word boundary. Start by building a vector of those tokens and then apply rules 1 and 2. You could represent tokens as `enum class TokenType {Consonant, Vowel, WordBoundary}; struct Token {TokenType type; std::string_view content; };`

Comment: Research the functions: `std::toupper`, `std::tolower`.  These can reduce the number of compares, by setting the case of the letter before you compare.  Search the internet for "std::string transform lowercase".

Comment: Good question. I do not understand the downvote. I would make a copy of the original, replacing the composite consonants, which can be easily hyphenated and when it's done, I would use that to know where I need to perform hyphenation in the original. I have elaborated on the idea in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to read them as a single consonant. You only need to interpret it that way.

This is how the task looks alike:

> VCCV -> VC-CV
>
> VCV -> V-CV except if it is VCe and it is the end of the word
>
> Never divided single consonants: “qu”, “tr”, “br”, “str”, “st”, “sl”, “bl”, “cr”, “ph”, “ch”

A simple approach to solve the problem would be to first copy the string in such a manner that in the copy you replace qu, tr, br, str, st, sl, bl, cr, ph, ch with some single consonant, no matter which one. So you have an original, where no changes were made (you will need it later) and a "damaged" copy, where you replaced all the strange consonants with "d" or some other constant (no matter which one, because from now on on the copy you can ignore rule 3).

Take a look at the copy and add hyphens to the appropriate places, store the indexes of the hyphens in the copy. Now iterate the characters, looking both at the unmodified original and the hyphenated copy and wherever you see differences, you can be sure that it's a special consonant, so you need to add one to the index of the copy and 2 (or 3) to the index of the original.

It is advisable to use a constant for replacement of special consonants where their length is 2 and some other consonant when the length is 3, so you will have an easy time processing the original vs. the copy when you add the hyphens to the original based on the copy.